# Is there a way to array an object along multiple curves without having to duplicate the object for each curve

Tags: modifiers, workflow, instances

I am currently using array and curve modifiers to array a vertex along a curve and then instancing an object to that vertex in order to avoid the object getting warped or rotated while following the curve. For an example see image:

[image: 1]

The current project has over 30 edges that require the object to be arrayed along them and I'd while I could simply duplicate both the object and vertex and repeat the process for each curve, I'd prefer to avoid having 30+ identical vertices and objects as well as having to link all the objects so that it would update all of them when I update the mesh of the object. I'm hoping there's a way to either array the vertex along multiple curves or instance the object over multiple vertices so while I'd have a vertex for each curve It would still leave me with a single master object that I can edit and have the rest auto-update.

Edit:

I've figured out how to do most of the things I was trying to do, the only thing I'd like to figure out is if there's a way to permanently link modifier data so that if I remove the subsurface modifier on the master pillar it removes it on all of them. other than that I've figured out a way to have pillars array along multiple curves but maintain a separate object that I can edit so that it applies to all of them.

For anyone interested or confused about what I was doing, I have attached a blend file.

[image]

Finally, I want to thank @atomicbezierslinger for their patient help despite my lack of understanding on account of only having been learning how to use Blender for about a month.

Comment: Instances maybe

Comment: How many curves? How many vertices on each curve? Do you know that a parent and child relationship between two objects can be duplicated in its entirety ... two new objects with the same relationship?  I think your question would be clearer showing your modifiers.

Comment: How many curves, the 30+ edges are converted to curves. How many vertices on each curve, that varies per curve as the edges being converted to curves are varying in length from 4 meters to I believe the longest edge is about 16-20 meters. The only modifiers being used is the array and curve modifiers. My issue is that I'd like to maintain a single master object that can be edited or switched out for a different object without having to redo all the edges

Comment: There are multiple ways probably to address your issue. Again I suggest ... your question would be clearer showing your modifiers and showing a second sibling example.

Comment: What is the source of your data points? Are you experienced in Python? Are you open to a mesh rather than a curve, as demonstrated in the candidate answer below?  Are you open to Particles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parenting your pillar with linked data, you just need to parent a "Collection instance".

First, create a new collection with your master pillar.

[image]

Now, replace your "sub" master-pillars with instanced collections

[image]

Now every time you modify the "master" pillar, every other one will get modified exactly the same. Example with a displace modifier :

[image]

Moreover, if you add objects in the "Master" collection, they will also get duplicated, along with any of their respective modifiers :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Particle System above.  Objects are emitted from faces. All the particles can be changed with a single GUI entry. Non faces are ignored.  Carefully duplicate the settings.  The number setting should be suited to your case. [Particles/Face] <-- 1 and [Random] <-- False. Particles can conveniently represent a sequence of items.

Suit to your needs. You can arrange the faces with no connection to other faces.  My presentation was done with speed in mind.

[image]
Particles use collections.  The arrow in the image above.

Particles can efficiently reuse/instance mesh data. I would change your representation to a mesh with Particles.

Group instances bound to an [empty] can also efficiently represent your visuals.  More instances.

Both techniques can be searched here at BSE or the website that rhymes with NooNube.

---

[image].

Sharing a mesh data block. See the edit history if this interests you.